# Infinite AJAX Scroll - update script after new post loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm using [Infinite AJAX Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) plugin to load series of posts, similarly to a blog.

I want to use the plugin's very neat *[history](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/examples/history.html)* feature to load both older and newer posts. There will be too many posts and it is not feasible to update the url list in each post's code individually so I figured out I could load it by a PHP include function.

In `first.html` I load the list using PHP include function:

```
<div id="pagination">
  <a href="first.html" id="first">1</a>
  <a href="second.html" id="second">2</a>
  <a href="third.html" id="third">3</a>
  ....
</div>
```

and specify the next post in the code `next: '#second'`:

```
var ias = jQuery.ias({
  container:  '#posts',
  item:       '.post',
  pagination: '#pagination',
  next:       '#second'
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
ias.extension(new IASPagingExtension());
ias.extension(new IASHistoryExtension({ prev: '' }));
```

In `second.html` the list is identical (loaded using PHP) and the script is changed to `prev: '#first'` and `next: '#third'`:

```
var ias = jQuery.ias({
  container:  '#posts',
  item:       '.post',
  pagination: '#pagination',
  next:       '#third'
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
ias.extension(new IASPagingExtension());
ias.extension(new IASHistoryExtension({ prev: '#first' }));
```

The problem is that the script doesn't update after a new post has been loaded so it keeps loading the same post over and over again. If I open `first.html` the script keeps loading `second.html`, `second.html` etc. If I open `second.html` the script keeps loading `third.html`, `third.html` etc. Is there a way to reload the script from the new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe just doesn't seem possible. For this to work new javascript would have to be loaded and be executed via AJAX. This is not possible for all kinds of reasons, for example security.

The best option would be to add a specific a-tag for next and prev pages. That's how the plugin is designed. If you can update the IAS javascript code per page, then it should also be possible to update the pagination links per page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wrote a PHP script to which I pass `next` and `prev` variables and it returns the list with `a` tags added to the next and previous pages. It works great.